# How to wait for task & CC email with 2013 workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, office-365, email, tasks

**Goal**

I'm trying to make a workflow (2013) in O365 that requires this flow:

1. Create a task for UserA
2. Email UserA to notify about the task, and CC UserB
3. Wait for UserA to complete the task

Sounds simple, but I can't get past this. Here's what I've tried.

**Approach A**

Amazingly, it looks like these builtin steps are not capable of using the CC field. PLEASE correct me if I'm wrong; this is my preferred solution.

1. `Assign a task` or `Start a task process`

**Approach B**

As a workaround to this seeming glaring oversight in the workflow framework, I've tried manually re-creating the task functionality. But now I can't tell when the task is done.

1. `Assign a task`, don't `Wait for task completion`, and do set `WaiveAssignmentEmail` + `WaiveCancellationEmail`
2. `Email` To: UserA, CC: UserB
3. I'm stuck here - how do I wait for the task outcome? (yes, I have the ID at least)

**Can anyone explain how to wait for the task outcome, or give another approach that will meet the goal?**

EDIT:
Clarified that the purpose of the email (with CC) is to inform the user they have a task. Thus, it cannot happen after completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Wait for task completion" is an option under "Assign a task" window.

[image]

This task will wait until your workflow task completes. You can an add a `send an email` action after this.

**EDIT: Notify additional users about task assignment**

Here is small algorithm that solves issue

```
Parallel Block Begin
    Step: Assign a Task
    Begin
        Assign a Task: get Task ID
    END
    Step: Send an email
    BEGIN   
        Wait until Task ID generates
        email to the users
    End
END
```

The workflow will look as follow

[image]

Comment: Venkat, thanks for the answer. My question wasn't clear enough. I'll update it now. The purpose of the email (with CC) is to inform the user they have a task. Thus, it cannot happen after completion.

Comment: Got it. You have to copy additional users to the task assignment notification.   Am I right?

Comment: Venkat, it's a good suggestion, but that field only accepts 1 entry. Even if it allowed 2, everything in that top section relates to the task, so it would mean the task is assigned to multiple people.

Comment: What do you think about a parallel block. This can be run parallel to task assignment action. But this notification will be sent out separate from default task notification. Let me know if you want to go this route.

Comment: Venkat, it is another good solution. However, if email & blocking task are in parallel, I think there's no way for the email to know the TaskID (and thus the URL). The task step needs to complete before that info is available. And the purpose of the email is for linking to the Task.

Comment: If we can add a pause action before the email action. In the mean time `assign task action` will generate task id and that can be used in the email.

Comment: Venkat, I haven't tried this yet, but I believe it will work! Can you make another answer out of this so I can accept it? Perhaps a conditional loop checking TaskID until it is set (in case the task takes longer than the selected pause action).

Comment: I have updated my answer to support even there is a delay in task creation how it can be handled.

Comment: @Dan, did this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

when you use task actions in SPD it generates tasks in related task list. You can simply create another workflow on that related task list, which will send an email to the CC user. You can fetch any data from the item on which the workflow instance runs on by referencing it via [Workflow Item ID] field, which is available for task lists (i.e. Workflow Tasks) in SPD workflow designer. This is the cleanest approach which does not introduce any delays. Hope this helps.