# SP Designer workflow - Assign a Task -parallel block -not getting TaskID

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, email

In SharePoint designer 2013 workflow, I'm trying to get the TaskID by running "Assign a task" and a loop in parallel block as per [this link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/217301/how-to-wait-for-task-cc-email-with-2013-workflow#). Task is getting created but I can get Task ID only when task ends not when pending.. How to get the TaskID while task is pending ? please advise.
Below is screenshot of my workflow
[image]

Comment: I need taskID to form the link to current task and also to get few task fields to show in email which will be sent to multiple users in CC

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2013 workflow engine works differently from that of SharePoint 2010 workflow. You will not get the taskid here. One possibility could be:

1. Calling a 2010 workflow within 2013 workflow and creating tasks using that. In 2010 W/F you can then update a column in the same list with the task id.
2. You can then pick the task id of 2010 W/F task from the list column in the 2013 workflow.